# apply a color value depending on decimal value imported

Tags: c#

To start with, I'm very new to C#!

I have a file with approximately 3 million lines. Each line contains a number between 0 and 1 (6 decimal places).

What I want to do is create a RGB value for each number depending where between 0 and 1 that number lies. For example, 0 would be green, 1 would be red, and all the numbers between would have a RGB value between green and red, created to represent how far down the color scale it is.

How do I calculate that RGB value?

Comment: I took the liberty to tidy up your question a bit. Hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest approach would be:

```
int red = (int)(Num * 255);
int green = (int)((1 - Num) * 255);
int blue = 0;
```

This way you get a gradient between red and green with green at 0 and red at 1.

[image: Green - Red gradient]

However it sounds like you want to produce a visual scale for values that range from "good" to "bad". In that people often also want to place yellow in the middle to denote "okayish" values. Here's the code for that:

```
int red, green, blue;
if ( Num < 0.5 )
{
    red = (int)(Num * 2 * 255);
    green = 255;
    blue = 0;
}
else
{
    red = 255;
    green = (int)((2 - 2 * Num) * 255);
    blue = 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great thank you! do you know how i would calculat the maximum value in the list "Num" that is less than 1 ?

Comment: `nums.Max(x => x < 1);` should do it.

Comment: thanks for  that, i get the error message 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'Max.. do you know what this means?

Comment: Wait, what do you want? Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: the list of numbers 'Num' contains values greater than 1.. my idea was to find the highest value that is equal to or less than 1 and make that the red value, and everything else would be picked up after . does that make sense ?

Comment: what i want to do is be able to control the top value of the color scale.. as it will vary depending on the file that i feed through the program... the one thing that will stay consistent is that it will always be =< 1.. for example one of the files red value will be .9 beacuse that is the highest value that is smaller than 1 in the file however another file i have the highest value is .25 so in that case the red value on the color scale would be .25.. hope this helps.

Comment: @TD - I see. That's a little bit more complicated, and I don't have time at the moment to write it all out. You say that you are new to C#. Are you new to programming as well? Or would you be able to write this code in another programming language? If so, then perhaps I could help you with the translation to C# - that would be quicker.

Comment: @Vilx-, i have experience with visual programming quite different, but i will it work out a way to do it. thank you for your assistance to this point !

Comment: @TD - The basic idea is this: you know that at value X you want color A, and at value Y you want color B. Then for a value Z, which is between X and Y, you figure out where exactly it is between them (`k=(z-x)/(y-x)`) and then for each r/g/b channels blend them appropriately (`b*k+a*(1-k)`). It's called "linear interpolation".

Comment: @Vilx-, Thanks for the advice will look into it.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to derive an algorithm to convert your decimal value to three separate values, Red, Green, and Blue. Then use the built-in Color type to create your color with those values (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx).

What you do with the colors from there is up to you.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because I didn't write the code for him? SO isn't for answering homework questions.